# jOOQ convert String to Boolean

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I have a table in MySQL with some columns (MD5, FLAGCONFIRMED, FLAGCHANGEPASSWORD) defined like "char(1)" where the only possible values are 0 and 1. I want jOOQ to convert these to Boolean in the code generation.

I created a converter:

```java
public class BooleanConverter implements org.jooq.Converter<String, Boolean>{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -4785961538634851898L;

   @Override
   public Boolean from(String arg0) {
      if (arg0 == null) {
         return null;
      }
      return arg0.equals("1");
   }

   @Override
   public Class<String> fromType() {
      return String.class;
   }

   @Override
   public String to(Boolean arg0) {
      if (arg0 == null) {
         return null;
      }
      return arg0.booleanValue() ? "1" : "0";
   }

   @Override
   public Class<Boolean> toType() {
      return Boolean.class;
   }

}
```

Then I configured the converter in my pom (I'm using maven to generate the source).

```
<customTypes>
  <customType>
    <name>java.lang.Boolean</name>
    <converter>org.test.converter.BooleanConverter</converter>
  </customType>
</customTypes>

<forcedTypes>
  <forcedType>
    <name>java.lang.Boolean</name>
    <expressions>.*\.FLAGCHANGEPASSWORD,.*\.FLAGCONFIRMED,.*\.MD5.*</expressions>
  </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

The code is successfully generated but the types aren't converted their type is still String.

```java
/**
 * The table column <code>mmw.enduser.MD5</code>
 */
public final org.jooq.TableField<de.kybeidos.mmw.data.tables.records.EnduserRecord, java.lang.String> MD5 = createField("MD5", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.CHAR, this);
```

How do I make it work?

**Edit**: I'm using jOOQ 2.6.1

Comment: Did you try using the **`java.lang.Character`** as a **fromType** of Converter? (Instead of String)

Comment: lschin, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in jOOQ-codegen. While the documentation clearly states that several regular expressions can be provided...

```
<forcedTypes>
  <forcedType>
    <!-- Specify again he fully-qualified class name of your custom type -->
    <name>java.util.GregorianCalendar</name>

    <!-- Add a list of comma-separated regular expressions matching columns -->
    <expressions>.*\.DATE_OF_.*</expressions>
  </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Taken from 
http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/

... The source code actually interprets the `<expressions/>` content as a single regular expression. Try the following, instead, replacing commas by pipes:

```
<expressions>.*\.FLAGCHANGEPASSWORD|.*\.FLAGCONFIRMED|.*\.MD5.*</expressions>
```

In fact, commas shouldn't be used to separate regular expressions as commas can have regex-semantics as in `{a, b}` or user-input semantics. I have filed [#2076](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2076) to fix that in jOOQ 2.7, 3.0

Note, you don't have to write your custom converter for booleans. You can force the `BOOLEAN` JDBC type onto your columns like this:

```
<forcedTypes>
  <forcedType>
    <name>BOOLEAN</name>
    <expressions>.*\.FLAGCHANGEPASSWORD|.*\.FLAGCONFIRMED|.*\.MD5.*</expressions>
  </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, it works. Does this JDBC BOOLEAN type works even if my field is a char(1)?

Comment: @islon: Yes, it just forces jOOQ's `DataType` reference for that column to `SQLDataType.BOOLEAN`. JDBC can then properly handle booleans through JDBC API methods like `PreparedStatement.setBoolean(int, boolean)`, or `ResultSet.getBoolean(int)`. If you find something not working in that area, feel free to report a bug to the [user group](https://www.google.ch/search?q=jooq-user) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ)